# Vmware Ubuntu 16 black screen

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, vmware, windows-10-upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 16 within Vmware Workstation player 12.5 on Windows 10. After the Windows 10 Anniversary edition update I can boot the virtual ubuntu machine up to the login screen. However, from there onwards, I only get a black screen. I think that it probably does login in but I am not able to see any display. I assume some display setting has been changed by the recent windows 10 upgrade which is affecting the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try first installing the VMware Tools in *VM/Install VMware tools..* and follow the prompts to install it, and then restart your VM.

> The Open Virtual Machine Tools (open-vm-tools) are the open source implementation of VMware Tools. They are a set of guest operating system virtualization components that enhance performance and user experience of virtual machines.

If it doesn't work,  Have you tried reinstalling VMware? Does the problem persist?

Oracle VM + Guest additions. It is a excellent alternative you should give it a try.

Comment: I already have Vmware tools installed. I have the option to update them (via `Player/Manage`) but to do so I have to be logged into the guest operating system. This is the point at which the screen goes black. If I reinstall Ubuntu or use another Virtualisation tool, I will lose the work saved in this Guest OS.

Comment: Sorry my bad, when I said reinstalling Ubuntu I meant reinstalling the VMware. Once done it, run the virtual machine again and see. Use other computer with VMware if necessary with your VM so you can discard if there is a problem with the VMware or with the VM

Comment: I did reinstall VMware and to no avail. I also converted the vmware machine to ovf format so I can run with VirtualBox, but I get exactly the same issue with a black screen after login.

Comment: do you have access to another computer? try to rule out if there is a problem with WMware + your win10, we can go from it. If still doesn't work you might have to try to recover Ubuntu, sorry.

Comment: I don't have another machine easily accessible I'm afraid. How would I recover ubuntu? I do have another guest OS (Suse linux) running in VirtualBox and that one still runs fine.

Comment: What if you install VMware inside Suse and try to run your ubuntu? remember we want to be 100%. We can also try this: create a clean ubuntu installation with the same configuration you used before and once is done swap the configuration file of your broken ubuntu with the new one. Please, before you try anything do a Backup!!! To recover Ubuntu, press [Shift] when is booting to bring the `grub menu` and boot your Ubuntu CD and then I guess we need another threat. If you want the short answer you gotta mount /root and your disk then update your packets or do a backup of your files.